# How is the grub boot menu presented if the gpt looks for efi system partition

Tags: linux, boot

I noticed that all grub resouces (fonts,images etc.) are located in `/boot/grub`, which usually exists in Linux filesystem partition. Of course there is another partition, which is mounted on `/boot/efi`. I believed that gpt looks for mounts and uses a partition that is mounted on `/boot/efi` (Efi system partition) since it contains the .efi files that actually boot the system.

My question is: How can all the resources of the boot menu be loaded if the gpt points to the efi partition, and if all the resources for grub boot manager are located in a different partition? If the gpt points to efi partition shouldn't the os be booted without any menu since this partition only contains the efi boot files?

Answer (score 1):

> Now i believed that gpt looks for,mounts and uses a partition

The GPT is just the partition table; it doesn't look for anything or mount anything. The *system firmware* (UEFI) is what does all the looking.

> How can all the resources of the boot menu be loaded if the gpt points to the efi partition, and if all the resources for grub boot manager are located in a different partition?

GRUB has its own filesystem drivers built-in; it's capable of using UEFI "raw device access" functions to access the contents of various filesystems – very much like an OS. (In fact, much like a real OS, GRUB even has its own drivers for PCI, SATA, NVMe, etc. so it doesn't need to rely on the firmware for anything.)

When you do `grub-install`, it builds the GRUB "core image" (grubx64.efi) that consists of the GRUB kernel and all of the necessary driver modules needed to access /boot, as determined by grub-install. (The location of the /boot partition gets embedded into grubx64.efi as well.) Running it with `--verbose` would probably show that it's including part_gpt.mod, ext2.mod, etc. into the final executable.

GRUB actually works the same way on BIOS, only the "core image" is stashed somewhere else on disk (and is loaded indirectly via the MBR).

That being said, UEFI itself is not strictly limited to one partition; an UEFI program can access files from any partition that the firmware understands. Another boot manager, rEFInd, actually loads *UEFI drivers* for the filesystems it needs to access.

Comment: So if i understood correctly,uefi finds and mounts efi system partition by looking at gpt,and then grub  somehow loads all the resources for its boot manager?

Comment: No, it looks for the ESP (EFI System Partition). You still didn't understand that GPT is just a partitioning *type*, *it doesn't look for anything or mount anything. The system firmware (UEFI) is what does all the looking.* Terminology matters!

Comment: @User: Yes, that's correct. (The "boot entries" in the mainboard's NVRAM indicates to UEFI _which_ partition to use; the GPT indicates _where_ that partition is.)